# Appending previous data in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am parsing data to a table view, but there are lakhs of names in the server page.

First, I wrote all the server data in different pages in the server side and I put a "View more" button under the table view. When the user clicks that, the page number will be increased by one and data on the second page is shown to the table view. The problem is that I lose the first page's data in the table view. How can I append the new data to the previous data when I click "View more"?

This is the `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    sharedClass=[SharedClass sharedInstance];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    Noresult.hidden = YES;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // NSString *userid = [defaults objectForKey:@"userid"];
    NSString *userid = @"3";

    NSString *search_key = @"";
    NSString *type=@"user";

    page = 1;

    ServerRequests *ser_req = [[ServerRequests alloc] init];
    ser_req.server_req_proces = self;
    NSString *postdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"{\"function\":\"search\",   \"parameters\": {\"user_id\": \"%@\",\"search_key\": \"%@\",\"type\": \"%@\",\"page\": \"%d\"},\"token\":\"\"}",userid,search_key,type,page];

    [ser_req sendServerRequests:postdata];

    NSLog(@"array=========>>%@",postdata);
    sharedClass.oprtn = @"load table";

}
```

And this is code inside `viewMore` button

```
-(IBAction)Viewmore:(id)sender
{


    NSString *userid = @"3";

    NSString *search_key = searchBaar.text;
    NSString *type=@"user";

    page = page + 1 ;



    ServerRequests *ser_req = [[ServerRequests alloc] init];
    ser_req.server_req_proces = self;
    NSString *postdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"{\"function\":\"search\",  \"parameters\": {\"user_id\": \"%@\",\"search_key\": \"%@\",\"type\": \"%@\",\"page\": \"%d\"},\"token\":\"\"}",userid,search_key,type,page];

    [ser_req sendServerRequests:postdata];

    sharedClass.oprtn = @"load table";

}
```

Comment: where are you saving those datas ?

Comment: @Midhun MP Saving to a server, posting those datas to that server

Comment: I mean in the application, where are you saving the data , and from where you are loading the data to tableView (usaually it's `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`)

Comment: oh yea..thats in NSMutableArray

Comment: Ohhh sorry...its NSArray I am using

Comment: Use NSMutableArray to store data and then update the index path of your tableView. Suppose, if you have ten rows in your tableview then on the next call you want to add ten more (which in your case is a page).Calculate the new indexes which will be {0,10},{0,11}....{0,19} and then update the tableview. Let me know if you want more clarification on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an `NSMutableArray` for keeping the data.
When you pressing the view more button, probably storing data like:

```
yourDataArray = //getting data from server;
```

I'll suggest don't **remove** or **reassign** the same `NSMutableArray`.

Use a temporary array Instead and append the new data from the temporary array to `dataArray` like:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = //getting data from server;

for(int loop = 0; loop < [tempArray count]; loop++)
{
   [yourDataArray addObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:loop]];
}
```

Comment: while pressing view more


-(IBAction)moreResults:(id)sender
{

    
   page = page + 1 ;
    
    
    

    
    
   ServerRequests *ser_req = [[ServerRequests alloc] init];
    ser_req.server_req_proces = self;
    NSString *postdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"{\"function\":\"search\", \"parameters\": {\"user_id\": \"%@\",\"search_key\": \"%@\",\"type\": \"%@\",\"page\": \"%d\"},\"token\":\"\"}",userid,search_key,type,page];
    
    [ser_req sendServerRequests:postdata];
     sharedClass.oprtn = @"load table";
    
 }

Comment: @ Midhun MP...Hey midhun i just want to show the datas on previous pages thats all,
means on button click it will be int page1 =page+1;
 i also wish to make it int page2 = page;

Comment: @NithinMK: 1) you need to use NSMutableArray instead of NSArray
2) please show the data adding code

Comment: Hey midhun...I have a doubt,If we parse lakhs of data to uitable view,it will not be any memory issue because i am using dequereusableCell function, but will it be a memory problem..because we will store it in an array before calling to tableview

Comment: @NithinMK: It'll cause memory issues with the data because, there will be a lot of memory allocated for the objects in the array. It' won't cause any memory issues related to tableView

Comment: @NithinMK : if you are not storing any heavy objects like :UIImage, NSData then your application won't cause any memory issues. Because usually the text data won't take that much of memory.